# Detecting UIButton touches on a subview

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, subview, ibaction

I have added a subview which contains a UIButton control. This subview is added to its superview programatically. I need to perform an action when this button is tapped, but since it's contained within its own subview, I can't hook an IBAction up to the view controller in order to push another view controller.

Is there an easy way to detect that the button is tapped and call a method within its super view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything programmatically:

```
[buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(methodName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then create your method:

```
- (void)methodName:(id)sender
{
     // Do something.
}
```

This is all you have to code.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I was making it way harder that it should have been!