# subviews with UIButtons - how to connect the buttons to IBActions

Tags: uibutton, connection, storyboard, xib, subview

I am trying to create a simple app which uses a main view and has a smaller subview within it. I need to have buttons in the subview and I am having trouble getting the connections for the buttons to work. I have done the following:

- Create a new View-based project, which gave me the ViewController.h & .m, the MainStoryboard.storyboard and the AppDelegate.h & .m.
- Create the subView using NewFile - Objective-C Class - then naming it "subView1" and making it a subclass of UIViewController and checking the with xib check box.
- This gave me the subView1.h &.m files and the subView1.xib.
- I then re-sized the subView in the xib, by setting it's size to "FreeForm" in the attributes inspector and then specifying the width (to 280) and height (to 300) in the size inspector. I also change the background colour to differentiate it from the main view.
- I then dragged a UIButton into the subView and connected it as an IBAction (which i named "clickButton1") to the subView1.h file using touchupinside.
- For testing purposes only i then used a simple NSLog to check the functionality of the button which i placed in the subView.m file as follows:

> -(IBAction)clickButton1:(id)sender {
>
> NSLog(@"It Worked!");
>
> }

- In my ViewController.m file in the viewDidLoad i then added the following code to add the subview to the main view:

> subView1 *sv1 = [[subView1 alloc]init];
>
> sv1.view.frame = CGRectMake(20,120,280,300);
>
> [self.view addSubview: sv1.view];

This all worked fine, and when i run the app i get the main view and the subview appear as expected. The problem is when i click on the button which is located in the subview it crashes with the following error:

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xe00000008)

From what i have read i believe this may have something to do with how I am adding the subview and the fact that I am using ARC. Something about once the subview is added it is automatically released and therefore all buttons/connections etc within the subview are lost.

So my two questions are 1) Am i missing something silly here and is there an easy fix? and 2) Is this an appropriate way to create an app which uses subviews with buttons within them or is there a better way? Thanks to anyone who takes the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reiterate what you said.

So you first made a View-Based Application (checking the "Use Storyboards" checkbox), and you put a button in the storyboard. Then, you control-dragged the button to the `"ViewController.h"` file. If that is right, you should just be able to put

```
NSLog(@"It Worked!");
```

in the method implementation (at least, **I** could do that)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response! No that is not what I did. I have no problem placing a button in the main view and connecting it directly to the ViewController.h. What I did is to create a new obj-C class called "subView1" and placed in the button in the new class's xib using interface builder. I cannot connect the button directly to the ViewController.h, but i can connect it to subView1.h. I then put the NSLog(@"It Worked") in the subView1.m implementation file.

Comment: Why can't you connect the button straight to ViewController.h?

Comment: I have not put the button in the storyboard because i want it in the subview. This is because I want to make multiple subviews, each with their own xib. And in the main views I want to swap/switch between these different subviews, and each subview will have a different set of buttons. Think, for example, of a main screen which contains a custom key-pad (the keypad would be a subview of the main view). Then, in response to an action, i want to switch to a different looking keypad, with different buttons. I don't want a whole new Viewcontroller because aspects of the main view will be unchanged.

Comment: I see.  I have never used any subviews before, so I don't know.  I will create a new project to try to find the solution.  I will try to come back to you as soon as possible, and if I find the solution, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Also, from what I understand, I think you are right when you say that all of your button's connections are lost.

Comment: So I tried the program, and it did crash, but with a different error.  It said: `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Okay. I think, instead of any IBActions, use the addTarget method. (I thought of it myself, then found out about this similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733144/detecting-uibutton-touches-on-a-subview?rq=1.)

Comment: Hmm... it still has a problem.  I don't know how to do it now. Sorry.  Like I said, I've never used subviews, so I don't know.

Comment: Or, (I'm not pushing you), you can just put the button in the storyboard and put the action in the ViewController class.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! In this instance i really do need to be able to use buttons in subviews. I believe I have found a solution after working through this example : http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/miscellaneous/handling-subviews-of-the-main-view-in-uiviewcontroller-part-1/ This worked when creating the subviews programatically, I'm about to try using xibs. It basically uses a protocol and delegate to get the job done. I will let you know if i can use this approach with xibs. Thanks again for your help though.

Comment: I used to use nibs, but I wasn't able to do a lot of stuff, so I switched to storyboards, and now I am in love with storyboards.  (Just my opinion!)

Comment: I also think storyboards seem like a pretty nice way of doing things, however I do not know how to achieve what i what I am trying with storyboards either. I have tried using a container view and placing a tab bar view controller in the container view. This works OK, but i would need to hide the tab bar (presumably programatically). Is this how you would do this using storyboards? I feel i would still be confronted with the same problem - that is how to connect the UIButtons to IBActions when the buttons are not in the main view controller.

Comment: What I like about storyboards is that you can create the functionality where on a click of a button, you can go to another view controller.  To do that, you can just right-drag a button to another view controller and select your segue type.

Comment: I understand that. But that's not quite what i want. If I simply go to a whole other view controller i get a whole new view. If i wanted both views to contain, for example, the same table, then this would need to be replicated in both view controllers. Instead, i want only part of the screen to switch to a new view. This is why i am trying to use subviews (or in storyboards a container view). Do you know how to achieve this using storyboards?

Comment: I know.  I just wanted to tell you why I like storyboards.